# Passing parameters to index() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have the following structure for my application:

```
myapp/index.php: index page
myapp/mycont/myfunc/productID: dedicated page for product
```

`index.php` has links that open up `myapp/mycont/myfunc/productID`

Hence, the controller functions are defined as:

```
index() {...}
myfunc($id) {...}
```

As, both my functions are almost same I wanted to remove the `myfunc()` function and change the URLs as:

```
myapp/: index page
myapp/productID: dedicated page for product
```

Both the above URLs should use `index()` function, but the index function throws error if I try to pass parameters to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pass parameter to index function in CI:**

1) You need the **`index`** segment **`http://www.example.com/search/index/search-keyword`**.
2) Or you need to use a route **`$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';`** 
3) Or try **remap**: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

**Edit (sample):**

```
$route['abc/campaigns/add_webengage_feedback_leads'] = "abc/campaigns/add_webengage_feedback_leads";
$route['abc/campaigns/add_webengage_survey_leads'] = "abc/campaigns/add_webengage_survey_leads";
$route['abc/campaigns/add_canvass_data'] = "abc/campaigns/add_canvass_data";
$route['abc/campaigns/add_connecto_data'] = "abc/campaigns/add_connecto_data";
$route['abc/campaigns/(:any)'] = "abc/campaigns/index/$1";
```

**Note:** The URL mapping to the `index` function should be last.

Comment: If i am using this $route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1'; It will be affect all methods which are in search controller. How i can make?

Comment: That's true. Hence you have to define all the URLs in the routes for that particular controller noting that the URL mapping to the index function should be the last. Please check edits.

Comment: There have no one any alternate option. Bcz i have too many methods in one controller. So its not possible to route every method. It's not right way i think so.

Comment: There's no other way round. And actually in other Frameworks like Laravel, Django, RoR we define URLs for each and every methods of `Views` (which is `Controller` of CI)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have removed the `index.php` from  your `URL`, you can go by this flow,

```
function index(){
    if( $this->uri->segment(3) ){     //if an product id is set
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3); //this is the product id in third segment of URL
    }else{                            //display the normal index page

    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Though, I want to change the URLs of type: `myapp/mycont/myfunc/productID` to `myapp/productID`

Comment: instead of segement(3) i used segment(2). Thanks for this bro